# Objective C Building html string

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, email

I am trying to put a html table into the body of an email.  To do this I am trying to build a string that contains the html.  I am getting an error though when I try to add a line that includes quotes within the html.  How can I ignore these quotes, and just capture the entire line?

```
BodyRiskMatrix = [BodyRiskMatrix stringByAppendingFormat:@"font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}"];
```

Xcode views the Calibri and sans-serif as variables.  Do I need to just delete all of the quotes within the html?

Comment: Just escape the quotes, \", as usual might I add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use a \ before any of your quotes**

```
 [BodyRiskMatrix stringByAppendingFormat:@"font-family:\"Calibri\",\"sans-serif\";}"];
```

this is how you use an escape in C-type languages.

If you want to add HTML to an email you can add an HTML file to your project and then do

```
    [mailController setMessageBody:htmlFile isHTML:YES];
```